# Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer WriteTo does not insert in DB (although AuditTo works fine)

Tags: .net, sql-server, serilog

In an ASP.NET MVC project .NET 4.5.2, I am using Serilog 2.10.0 and `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer` (5.6.1) to write to custom columns of SQL Server.

The `AuditTo` method works fine and inserts the error to the db but the `WriteTo` does not.

Although they both use the same configuration and credentials, I specifically gave `INSERT` & `SELECT` permissions to the user (suggested in another answer here). I am aware that `AuditTo` throws exceptions when an error arises during the process but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong when using `WriteTo`.

Could you give me a hint?

Thanks !

```
var connstring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString"];

var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions();
sinkOpts.TableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName"];
sinkOpts.AutoCreateSqlTable = false;
sinkOpts.BatchPostingLimit = 1;

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .MinimumLevel.Verbose() 
              .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connstring,
                       columnOptions: GetSqlColumnOptions(),
                       sinkOptions: sinkOpts,
                       restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose);

return log.CreateLogger();
```

Additionally I tried to enable debug with no success. I might doing something wrong but no error is displayed in the output window.

```
_logger.Error("{Error_Message}", "TEST");
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Serilog sinks like the SQL Server sink write messages on a background thread when you use `WriteTo` (asynchronous) whilst `AuditTo` always write messages immediately (synchronous).

If your application ends before the background thread was able to send the messages, they are lost and that is likely what's happening in your case...

It's your responsibility to flush the logs before your application ends. See [Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers).

You do that by calling `Log.CloseAndFlush()` or by disposing your logger.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        // ...
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <##<##<##<##<##<##
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Augusto and thank you for your response ! I had read your response in another thread while searching for a solution and I have already added the CloseAndFlush method after logging the error.
My question is where AuditTo and Write To differ? I suspect that it is related to custom columns since if I use the default table everything runs smoothly for both WriteTo & AuditTo